# How to upgrade GitLab FOSS from 12.7.5 to 12.8.5 (Omnibus package)?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using GitLab server (community) 12.7.5 . How to upgrade GitLab FOSS from 12.7.5 to 12.8.5 (Omnibus package)?

Answer (score 0):

Login as `root` user. With Omnibus, Ubuntu 16.04 . Need about 20 - 25 minutes to finish.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gitlab-ce
gitlab-ctl restart
```